# Does the Struts2 <s:set> tag escape HTML by default?

Tags: jsp, struts2, escaping, struts-tags, html-escape

Unless `escapeHtml="false"` is explicitly set, the `<s:property>` tag escapes HTML by default:

```
<s:property value="someValue" />
<!-- the HTML contained in "someValue" will be escaped. -->
```

Does `<s:set>` also behave this way ?

```
<s:set var="myVariable" value="someValue" />
<!-- will the HTML contained in "someValue" be escaped ? -->
```

Comment: The real question is why not upvoting the answer... BTW I've edited the question since the culprit for the downvote seemed to be a lack of clarity. Now it should be crystal clear.

Comment: Exactly. Thanks Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, [`<s:set>`](https://struts.apache.org/docs/set.html) tag doesn't escape anything on its own.

But you can exploit the `<s:property />` escaping capabilities by using it in the `<s:set/>` body.

Not escaped:

```
<s:set var="myVariable" value="someValue" />
```

Escaped:

```
<s:set var="myVariable">
    <!-- the following value will be escaped -->
    <s:property value="someValue" />
</s:set>
```